# Using model directly in the view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named "Category". It is just a list of descriptions stored in the database. Now I want the category descriptions to appear in a drop down list.

Would the correct thing be to make an instance variable in the action where I say something like `@categories = Category.all` or do you use `Category.all` directly in the view?

What would be the shortcomings/advise against using the model directly in the view?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the model directly in the view?

Comment: I personally don't see a problem with using the model directly in the view in this kind of situation.

Comment: @jonallard, you could say that in this situations the extra instance variable clutters the controller. Especially because he probably has to set it in multiple actions.

Answer (score 1):

If Category.all is being called in the view only once, it's OK to write it directly. Else, it's better to write a helper rather than creating instance variables as per Rails convention. Something like

```
def all_categories
  @all_categories ||= Category.all
end
```

It does a single query, if being used multiple times in the same view as well.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to create the instance variable in the controller for the data which is specific to that request.

For you Category example, doing the query directly from the view is appropriate.

Could be in the view for that action, a partial, or even in the layout if it's used throughout the site.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rule of thumb is to only save method results in instance variables if it saves you some code duplication because you want to use the result twice. Another rule of thumb is to never call methods that have side effects in your views. In this case it seems you are using a method without side effects once, so I would be okay with putting it in a view.

That said it is a lot easier to lose sight of your model method calls in your views than in your controller since they are mixed with the markup elements. That might cause you to overlook that you have called Category.all before when adding some new code in your view that also calls Category.all. Instead of easily noticing in your controller that you have an instance variable for Category.all, you are stuck with either going through your whole view or forgetting to do so.

Another case to make for using instance variables is that it can make your views easier to reuse. Instead of tightly coupling your view to the Category class, you might want to make the calls that are done on the instance variable generic enough to also be applicable to other models that can be viewed in a similar way. Using instance variables this way can help you take advantage of the duck typing that Ruby offers, but you have to weigh the ease of making things generic against the effort of remembering or looking up what kind of methods are actually available on the different kinds of objects that could be inside your instance variable.